# gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known with imaplib.IMAP4_SSL in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, imap

I have a perfectly fine script that works fine when I run it locally to authenticate using IMAP4_SSL and `imaplib` as follows:

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host_incoming, port_incoming)
mail.login(user, password)
mail.list()
```

However, when I host this part of the code in the Google Cloud Functions, then I receive the error:

> gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known getaddrinfo
>   (/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py)

If I use Google Gmail credentials instead (for host, port, user and password), then no errors are provided and everything works fine. So what is wrong with the email or server that I am using and how could I check this?

Comment: Gaierror is the DNS name lookup failing.  Is your host internal?

Comment: No its managed by another company. This company is providing my internet connection. How can I test for the failing host?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a billing account for your the project containing your Cloud Function? Functions on the free tier cannot communicate with external networks and will fail DNS lookup.

Comment: Sorry, not implying you are cheap! Newly created functions will be on the free tier until a billing account is explicitly added.

Comment: You need to add billing for each cloud function??

Comment: No, for each new project. If the project already has billing added though, this might not be the cause.